# Could reflected sychrotron radiation guide electrons in the slit experiments?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

When electrons are accelerated they produce synchrotron radiation. An electron traveling from the slit toward a detection screen will produce photons along the way. These photons will radiate toward both walls producing familiar patterns. The majority of the reflected photons will come from these pattern points and will influence the trajectory of the traveling electron. The fact that there are no reflected photons from the slit is also an influence.
Could reflected synchrotron radiation affect electrons?

Comment: Wouldn't any light passing through a slit form an interference pattern, regardless of source? Assuming, of course, the dimensions are appropriate to cause single-slit interference.

Comment: I believe so but I'm talking about photons coming from the electron after it's gone through the slit. As the electron travels from the slit to the detection screen it can emit synchrotron radiation. As the radiation is reflected back-and-forth between the two walls a pattern forms depending on the distance between walls, the size of the slits and the frequencies. My question is could this radiation affects the trajectory of the electron as it travels toward the detection screen?

Comment: @BillAlsept electrons emit synchrotron radiation when accelerated. These electrons http://rdg.ext.hitachi.co.jp/rd/moviee/doubleslite-n.wmv once they leave the source ARE NOT ACCELERATED either before or after the slits, so no radiation is expected.end of story.  For your information  even in acceleration  and radiation due to it , the photons will be very low energy with respect to the electron energy and with velocity c to infinity, in a direction different than the direction of the electron, they can never interact again.

Comment: Reflection from walls will be random and in many directions, incoherent, and even for accelerated electrons their radiation after leaving cannot affect their path.

Comment: The electron could be accelerated if it bumped the edge of the slit as it came through and after that it could be bumped by the reflected photons. So radiation could be expected. Synchrotron radiation is very high energy and is why they use it in the highly sensitive experiments. A free electron is not bound to anything and could easily be influenced.

Comment: Yes the reflection would be random and could reflect back-and-forth thousands of times before the electron gets to the other side.